# Moodle: using mysql joins in $table = set_sql(); method

Tags: php, oop, moodle, moodle-api

I want to know how joins are applied for **$table= set_sql();** method.
I'm trying to render a table without using the conventional **html_table();** method.

A basic application for a single database table "mdl_user":

```
  $table->set_sql('*', "{user}", '1');
```

But I intend to achieve more complex sql query using joins as shown below:

```
    **SELECT aa.firstname, aa.email, zz.fullname
    FROM mdl_table1 aa
    INNER JOIN mdl_table2 zz
    ON aa.id = zz.userid WHERE lastlogin => ? and lastlogin <= ? GROUP BY firtname;**
```

This link below might be helpful. I've tried to work around it but still not clear about it. 
https://docs.moodle.org/dev/lib/tablelib.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this

```
$fields = 'aa.firstname, aa.email, zz.fullname',
$from = '{table1} aa
         INNER JOIN {table2} zz ON aa.id = zz.userid';
$where = 'lastlogin => :lastlogin1 and lastlogin <= :lastlogin2';
$params = array('lastlogin1' => $lastlogin, 'lastlogin2' => $lastlogin);
$table->set_sql($fields, $from, $where, $params);
```